# Exporting Greek characters on PDF show as boxes

Tags: laravel, pdf

I am trying to export a pdf from Laravel using laravel-dompdf and then send it via email. When i open the pdf with Chrome the pdf displays just fine, but when i open the pdf with Acrobat Reader the Greek characters display as squares. I am using the DejaVu Sans font which supports Greek. I also have utf-8 encoding in the header of the html.

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('mails.registerMail', $data);
 Mail::send('mails.emailRegistration', $data, function($message)use($data,$pdf) {
        $message->to($data["email"], $data["team_name"])
        ->subject($data["subject"])
        ->attachData($pdf->output(),$data["team_name"] ."Invoice.pdf");
```

where data is an array with my information.

Comment: Most likely the PDF file does not have the font you are using embedded. In tha absence of the original font the reader must use a substitute. In the case od Chrome (presumably pdf.js) the font being used as a substitute contains the Greek characters, encoded at the expected position. However, it seems like the font Acrobat uses as a substitue either does not have the Greek characters or does not encode them at the same code point. Thus it draws the .notdef glyph, which for TrueType fonts is usually a hollow square. For reliable results you should always embed fonts.

Comment: when i go to acrobat's reader properties it lists all the embedded fonts, the DejaVu. However it is not displayed

Comment: Well if you don't supply the PDF file to look at, there's little anyone can do to help you.